# Find a subset of $X=[5,8)\cup[12,20]$ that is both open and closed in X.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is $E=[12,20]$ such a subset?

E is open: $\forall x\in [12,20],\ V_{1}(x)\subset E$

E is closed: $E^{c} = [5,8)$ is open since $\forall x\in [5,8),\ V_{1}(x)\subset E^{c}$

The metric is the absolute difference and $V_{1}(x)$ refers to the $1$ neighbourhood around $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: both $[12,20]$ and $[5, 8)$ as well as their union will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, from your word choices that you're using the subspace topology.  Since $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, to show $E=[12,20]$ is both open and closed, you need to find an open set $O$ and a closed set $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $E=X\cap C=X\cap O$.

- To show that $E$ is open in $X$, using the subspace topology, we need an open set $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $O\cap X=E$.  An example that will work is $(11,21)$.
- To show that $E$ is closed in $X$, using the subspace topology, we need a closed set $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $O\cap X=E$.  An example that will work is $[12,20]$.

Comment: In my answer I'm using the definition for open sets in metric spaces and showing a set is closed by showing that its compliment is open. Is that valid?

Comment: What is $V_1(x)$?

Comment: $V_{1}(x) = \{ y\in X \ s.t. |y-x|<1 \}$

Comment: Then, yes, that works, because $V_1(x)$ is the intersection of the ball $B_1(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:|x-y|<1\}$, which is open, with $X$.  Although, perhaps it would be good to explain why $V_1(x)$ is a subset rather than just claiming it is true.